# Yii Framework and HTML5 template file together

Tags: yii, yii2

I have one question: 
my website would be localhost/carfinancing/index.php

I have different index.php page right now which is in HTML5 template and Yii is installed in "application" directory.

When I copy paste this directory then localhost/carfinancing/application/web/ shows my yii index page and localhost/carfinancing/application/web/online-car-loan-application shows another page.

Is there way for yii index file to show: localhost/carfinancing/application and for another page, to show: localhost/carfinancing/online-car-loan-application ?
I mean to remove the '/web/' word from the url?

Comment: your question seems related  to yii2  urlManager  sees this guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: If I point host to "web" directly then what about localhost/carfinancing/index.php ? It has html5 template.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 questions here. I will work on answering both.

## 1 Your HTML5 template should be a view file in the views/[controller name]

Since Yii2 is an MVC framework it is designed to have all requests come to a controller which then provides a view. If you are placing files in web to be viewed directly you are losing out on the benefits of MVC.

## 2 In order to remove the web/ directory from the URL, you will need to use the url manager.

Add the urlManager in the component of the `config/web.php`

```
$config = [
...
'components' => [
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

You will also want to setup your .htaccess as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
 
RewriteEngine on
 
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then move everything out of the `public_html` directory, and put everything that is in the `web` directory back in `public_html`.

Reference this article if you are still having issues: http://fellowtuts.com/yii/hide-or-remove-basicweb-from-url-in-yii-2-0/

Comment: Let me try. I will let you know what happens if I try this.

Comment: Have you had any success?

Comment: No success. This is my structure. affiliate/
application/
build/
css/
images/
js/
login/
index.php

And yii2 is installed in application/ directory @Mmelcor.

Comment: Are you using the Basic or Advanced Yii2 template?